# Is this a breadth-first search algorithm?

Tags: python, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

So, I have this graph and I want to use the breadth-first search algorithm to see if there is a path from a vertex to another.

[image: Cool sketch of a graph]

So, I implemented a function in python which returns true or false, depending on the existence of a path and it works. Well, it worked for the tests I made. What I want to know is if this is indeed a breath-first search algorithm. I haven't seen any BFS algorithm before and I only know its base idea. I heard that BFS is implemented recursively, though I implemented it iteratively and that's why I have doubts about it.So, here are both the function and the representation of my graph:

```
outb = {1: [2, 3],
  2: [4, 5],
  3: [5, 11, 12],
  4: [6, 7],
  5: [7],
  6: [9, 10],
  7: [8],
  11: [3],
  12: [15, 14, 13],
  13: [17],
  14: [17],
  15: [12, 5, 8, 16],
  17: [18]}

def BFS(v1, v2):
    parsed = []
    toParse = [v1]
    current = v1

    while len(toParse) > 0:

        while current in parsed:
            current = toParse.pop(0)

        if current not in outb:
            return False

        if v2 in outb[current]:
            return True

        toParse += outb[current]
        parsed.append(current)

    return False
```

And the last questions I have is: Is BFS, by its nature, finding the shortest path from a vertex to another? I read this thing on the internet and I want to be sure.

Comment: Read the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). It looks like your code implements the algorithm there, and it states that BFS finds the shortest path.

Comment: Comparing your code to the pseudocode in the wikipedia, `S == parsed`, `Q == toParse`, `current == current`.

Comment: Your code is a BFS, but it's also wrong, because `current not in outb` doesn't mean there is no path, and you try to do `toParse.pop(0)` without considering whether `toParse` actually has any elements. Also, lists are not an efficient choice for most of the data structures used.

Comment: @user2357112 current not in outb is error checking to make sure you're not looking for a path from a node not in the graph. Also, the code DOES check whether toParse has any elements. The pop call happens in a while loop with that as a condition.

Comment: @DanHall: There are nodes in the graph that aren't `in outb`, because someone made the choice to omit keys from `outb` if they don't have outgoing edges. If the search reaches such a node before it reaches the destination, the search will wrongly output `False`.

Comment: @DanHall: While the outer `while` loop checks whether `toParse` has elements, the `toParse.pop(0)` call occurs inside a second `while` loop that performs no such check. If `toParse` consists only of elements `in parsed`, the inner `while` loop will remove all elements of `toParse` and then throw an exception.

Comment: Also, `outb` is missing a bunch of back edges, such as 6->4.

Comment: @DanHall: [Here's a demo](http://ideone.com/aPkhBg) of why terminating on `current not in outb` is wrong. There's an obvious path from 1 to 18, but the search returns `False` because it hits that `current not in outb` check and terminates before it finds the path.

Comment: @DanHall: Similarly, [here](http://ideone.com/aNeVII) (with a slightly different graph) is a demo of why that `pop` call is not properly checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a breadth-first search. It follows a fairly typical structure with the search frontier treated as a queue (although lists are an inefficient choice for a queue), and it considers nodes in order of distance from the root, like a standard breadth-first search.

However, it's also wrong. The `current not in outb` termination condition causes it to [wrongly output `False`](http://ideone.com/aPkhBg) for searches like `BFS(1, 18)`, and the `while current in parsed: current = toParse.pop(0)` loop can exhaust `toParse` and throw an exception when it tries to pop from an empty list, [demonstrated here](http://ideone.com/aNeVII) with a slightly different graph. Also, your `outb` doesn't match the picture of the graph it's supposed to represent; it's missing a bunch of back edges, such as 6->4.

Comment: So if I'd correct these mistakes and the graph representation it could be considered a "legit" BFS algorithm?

Comment: @Xyntell: I would already consider it a BFS, but it's not the BFS you want.

Comment: Ok. Got it! Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Xyntell code below in my answer corrects those mistakes (minus the missing back edges which you'll have to add into the dictionary if you want to account for them).

Answer (score 1):

This is a BFS algorithm, written to find whether a path exists, but it doesn't tell you what that path is, and doesn't account for the way your dictionary is structured to represent the graph.

Here's an example of a BFS for the above graph that can deal with the way your dictionary represents the graph. It returns the path when it finds one, and False when a path doesn't exist. If you just want it to return True when it finds a path, edit line 19 to `return True`

```
def BFS2(graph, v1, v2):
    '''
    graph: a dictionary representing an unweighted graph
    v1: a key in graph, representing the start node
    v2: a key and value in graph, representing the end node
    returns: a shortest path from v1 to v2, False if there is no path.
    '''
    if v1 not in graph:
        return False
    path_start = [v1]
    paths = [path_start]
    while len(paths):
        test_path = paths.pop(0)
        last_node = test_path[-1]

        for next_node in graph[last_node]:
            if next_node not in test_path:
                next_path = test_path + [next_node]
                if next_node == v2:
                    paths.append(next_path)
                    return next_path
                elif next_node in graph:
                    paths.append(next_path)
    return False
```

Comment: There's no requirement that a BFS has to actually return the path. Whether a search is a breadth-first search is simply a property of how the search is structured, not a matter of what it outputs.

Comment: @user2357112 got it. Thanks! Looks like i need to revisit my graph theory. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Better, but your implementation is buggy. It fails if `v1` has no outgoing edges, and since it uses no visited set, it can perform an exponential amount of redundant work. (Trying to use the path as the visited set doesn't stop it from redundantly considering exponentially many different paths to the same node.)

Comment: @user2357112 fixed to deal with the case where the client is searching for a path starting with a node that has no outgoing edges. It does account for visited nodes, though, as it only adds children if the next_node is not in test_path

Comment: That only prevents it from trying paths that loop back on themselves, though. It doesn't stop the search from putting 50 billion paths to the same node in `paths` and independently extending each and every one of them. It's not a correctness issue, but it prevents the search from finding the destination in a reasonable amount of time even for fairly small graphs. [Demo.](http://ideone.com/t3bN5q) (This isn't the only inefficiency, but it has by far the greatest effect.)

Comment: @user2357112 that's useful. What are the other inefficiencies?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143443/discussion-between-dan-hall-and-user2357112).

Answer (score -1):

No, This isn't a BFS algorithm. [This image will show you how a BFS algorithm would work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93PZs.gif)